# react native use let or var inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why i cant use javascript in jsx? I can only use things like array.map or filter. But if want to use more than one statement it does not work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {
         let a = 5
         if(a==5){return <Text>hello</Text>}
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Place that logic outside of the return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your logic outside of the return statement. I use this formatting, I think it is acceptable.

```html
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    let a = 5;
    
    return (
      {(a === 5) &&
        <Text>hello</Text>
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Also note the triple equal, to avoid type cohesion. This may not be necessary for your purposes but is best practice!